# Stacking children flex divs results in other non-stacked divs being behind stack

Tags: html, css

To stack items above each other (like a card deck) I use a `relative` positioned parent with the "cards" inside that are `absolute` positioned with `top: 0` and `left: 0`.
However, all following `divs` that are not part of the stack are placed behind the stack, which is not intended.
How can content be placed after the stack (the stack's height changes du to flex box)?

Here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/TheTho/pen/JjbpNxo).

```js
var current_index = 0;
function toggle(){  
    // Set class 'active'
    var cl = "active_card";
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    
    var last_index = current_index;
    
    current_index = current_index + 1;
    if ( current_index == elements.length ){
        current_index = 0;  
    }
    
    for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        var el = elements[i]
        if (last_index == i){
            el.classList.remove(cl);
        }
        else if (current_index == i){
            el.classList.add(cl);
        }
        else if (current_index == -1){
            current_index = 0;
            el.classList.add(cl);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    console.log("changed index from "+last_index + " to " +current_index);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --duration: 1500ms;
  --easing: ease-in-out;
}
.stack{ position: relative; }
.card{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}
.card .active_card { opacity: 1; }
.card:not(.active_card) { opacity: 0; }
.card { transition: opacity 0.3s linear; }
.red{background-color:red;}
.orange{background-color:orange;}
.inner{margin: 20px; width: 100%; background-color:gray; opacity: inherit;}

.active_rect > .inner { 
    animation: scale 1000ms infinite alternate linear;
    transition: transform-origin var(--duration) var(--easing);
    transform-origin: scale(1.1);
}

ul{list-style:none; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}
.datadummy{border: 2px solid green; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: white;}
```

```html
<button onclick=toggle()>Toggle</button>
<div>
  <h3>Heading 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="stack">
  <div class="card red active_card">
    <div class="inner">
      <ul>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
      </ul>             
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card orange">
    <div class="inner">
      <ul>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
        <li><div class="datadummy"/></li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Heading 2</h3>
```

Here is the css snippet that seems relevant for me - that works in sense of stacking elements, but is not suited for a real world usage due to the described problem.

```
.stack{position: relative;}
.card{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

Comment: Wrap the stacked divs in another div positioned relatively

Comment: Does not work. Did I understand you wrong? [Demo](https://codepen.io/TheTho/pen/abBqwJd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep at least one element in-flow by simply adding:

```
.card:first-child {
  position:relative;
}
```

Full code

```js
var current_index = 0;

function toggle() {
  // Set class 'active'
  var cl = "active_card";
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

  var last_index = current_index;

  current_index = current_index + 1;
  if (current_index == elements.length) {
    current_index = 0;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var el = elements[i]
    if (last_index == i) {
      el.classList.remove(cl);
    } else if (current_index == i) {
      el.classList.add(cl);
    } else if (current_index == -1) {
      current_index = 0;
      el.classList.add(cl);
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log("changed index from " + last_index + " to " + current_index);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --duration: 1500ms;
  --easing: ease-in-out;
}

.stack {
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card:first-child {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-flex;
}

.card .active_card {
  opacity: 1;
}

.card:not(.active_card) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.card {
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.inner {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: inherit;
}

.active_rect>.inner {
  animation: scale 1000ms infinite alternate linear;
  transition: transform-origin var(--duration) var(--easing);
  transform-origin: scale(1.1);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.datadummy {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=toggle()>Toggle</button>
<div>
  <h3>Heading 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="stack">
  <div class="card red active_card">
    <div class="inner">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card orange">
    <div class="inner">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Heading 2</h3>
```

Or consider CSS grid and add all of them above each other:

```
.stack {
  display:grid;
}

.card {
  grid-area:1/1;
}
```

Full code

```js
var current_index = 0;

function toggle() {
  // Set class 'active'
  var cl = "active_card";
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");

  var last_index = current_index;

  current_index = current_index + 1;
  if (current_index == elements.length) {
    current_index = 0;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var el = elements[i]
    if (last_index == i) {
      el.classList.remove(cl);
    } else if (current_index == i) {
      el.classList.add(cl);
    } else if (current_index == -1) {
      current_index = 0;
      el.classList.add(cl);
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log("changed index from " + last_index + " to " + current_index);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --duration: 1500ms;
  --easing: ease-in-out;
}

.stack {
  position: relative;
  display:grid;
}

.card {
  grid-area:1/1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.card .active_card {
  opacity: 1;
}

.card:not(.active_card) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.card {
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.inner {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: inherit;
}

.active_rect>.inner {
  animation: scale 1000ms infinite alternate linear;
  transition: transform-origin var(--duration) var(--easing);
  transform-origin: scale(1.1);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.datadummy {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=toggle()>Toggle</button>
<div>
  <h3>Heading 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="stack">
  <div class="card red active_card">
    <div class="inner">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card orange">
    <div class="inner">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="datadummy" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Heading 2</h3>
```